# Term for 'baby-talk'

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, speech

So many newly-weds have this practice of calling one another ridiculous but affectionate names i.e. honey-bunch, or 'bunny-boo' etc.

Is there a single-word term for this practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Hypocorism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypocoristic) might do the trick.  Otherwise a "term of endearment" is a specific hypocorism that addresses what you are talking about.

Comment: But personally I would go for drippy.

Comment: And, I see now that you wanted a single-word term...  Please be gentle in the down-votes. :)

Comment: Got it.  I love wikipedia.

Comment: Were I feeling snarky, I might suggest, "saccharinism."